# How to change params like Language or Voice on IBM project-intu setup on a Raspberry?

Tags: ibm-watson, project-intu

I was able to setup [project-intu](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/project-intu.html) successfully on my raspberry and it works great with the default dialog which is in english.

Now **I want to use my own Conversation Workspace which is in Spanish** and change the default Voice from en-US_MichaelVoice to es-ES_LauraVoice but I can't find which file should I update. I tried to update `bin/raspi/etc/profile/body.json` file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change m_Gender & m_Language in SpeakingAgent, it will automatically select a voice based on those values.